# SMOTE target variable not found in R

Tags: r, data-preprocessing, smote

Why is it when I run the smote function in R, an error appears saying that my target variable is not found? I am using the smotefamily package to run this smote function.

> tv_smote <- SMOTE(tv_smote, Churn, K = 5, dup_size = 0)

Error in table(target) : object 'Churn' not found

[Chunk Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YN8g.png)

[df data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmnEm.png)

[df 1st few rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5aKC.png)

Comment: It can be useful to include some kind of reproducible code for what `df` looks like for context. It doesn't need to be the exact data you use for your project, but an example that contains the same kinds of features.

Comment: Hi @CubicInfinity I have added some snapshots of df structure and 1st few rows for some context.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should include the minimum code and data needed to reproduce the problem. This saves time and gives you more chance of getting an answer. However, try this...

```
tv_smote <- SMOTE(tv_smote, tv_smote$Churn, K = 5, dup_size = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get the same error by doing this:

```
library(smotefamily)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:8, y = 8:1)

df_smote <- SMOTE(df, y, K = 3, dup_size = 0)
```

It appears to me that SMOTE doesn't know `y` is a column name. In the documentation, `?SMOTE`, it says that the `target` argument is "A vector of a target class attribute corresponding to a dataset X." My interpretation of this is that you need to supply a vector, not a name. Changing it to `df_smote <- SMOTE(df, df$y, K = 3, dup_size = 0)` gets past that part.

I am not familiar with the SMOTE function, but from testing it would appear that SMOTE cannot accept dataframes with any factor type columns. I get `Error in get.knnx(data, query, k, algorithm) : Data non-numeric` when using `as.factor`.

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error as well. Error in get.knnx(data, query, k, algorithm) : Data non-numeric. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Change all of your factor or string columns to numeric. You can use `as.numeric(df$colname)`.

Comment: One more thought, without actually doing my research n SMOTE: You may need to exclude your target variable from the dataframe you supply to the function to get the results you want.